# No limits of integration for electric field integral?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

For this problem,

[image]
[image]

The solution is,

[image]

However, why have they not included limits of integration? I think this is because all the small charge elements dq across the ring add up to Q.

**However, how would you solve this problem with limits of integration?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this is because all the small charge elements dq across the ring add up to Q.

Correct!

The limits here would be from 0 to Q.

If you wanted to, you could complicate the calculation by parameterizing $dq = \frac{Q}{2\pi} d\phi$ for some angle $\phi$ along the ring from 0 to $2\pi$, or by parameterizing $dq = \frac{Q}{2\pi R} dl$ from 0 to $2\pi R$ where $R$ is the ring radius and $dl$ is a length of the ring. Doing this complication could be more intuitive for some people, since it is an integral over a spatial coordinate.